# error: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [12,32] and labels shape [72]

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, nltk

I am trying to create a simple chat bot using lstm with my own data set
and I am using bag of word concept to get question.

I am getting this error

```
InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape 
[12,32] and labels shape [72]    [[{{node 
loss_23/lstm_72_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
```

My dataset:

```
     {"intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
     "responses": ["Hello, thanks for visiting", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
     "context_set": ""
    },
    {"tag": "goodbye",
     "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye"],
     "responses": ["See you later, thanks for visiting", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."]
    },
    {"tag": "thanks",
     "patterns": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful"],
     "responses": ["Happy to help!", "Any time!", "My pleasure"]
    },
    {"tag": "hours",
     "patterns": ["What hours are you open?", "What are your hours?", "When are you open?" ],
     "responses": ["We're open every day 9am-9pm", "Our hours are 9am-9pm every day"]
    },
    {"tag": "payments",
     "patterns": ["Do you take credit cards?", "Do you accept Mastercard?", "Are you cash only?" ],
     "responses": ["We accept VISA, Mastercard and AMEX", "We accept most major credit cards"]
    },
    {"tag": "opentoday",
     "patterns": ["Are you open today?", "When do you open today?", "What are your hours today?"],
     "responses": ["We're open every day from 9am-9pm", "Our hours are 9am-9pm every day"]
    }
  ]
}
```

my code

```
     from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM,Dense,Flatten
     from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
     import nltk
     from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
     stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

     import numpy 
     import tflearn
     import tensorflow
     import random
     import json
     import pickle

     with open("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\intents.json") as file:
             data = json.load(file)
#bag of words 
 here
words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []
print('array')
for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])
    print('pattern')
    if intent["tag"] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent["tag"])

words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
print(words)
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
labels = sorted(labels)

training = []
output = []

out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
    bag = []

    wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

    for w in words:
        if w in wrds:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)

    output_row = out_empty
    output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1
    print(output_row)
    training.append(bag)
    output.append(output_row)
training = numpy.array(training,dtype=numpy.float32).reshape(20,1,32)
output=numpy.array(output,dtype=numpy.float32).reshape(20,6,1)

 model=Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(1,32),activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
 model.add(LSTM(64,activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
 model.add(LSTM(32,activation='softmax',return_sequences=True))
 model.compile(optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'],loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(training,output,random_state=1,test_size=0.4)
 model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
```

## error

```
   InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-272-fae79c4d9f04> in <module>
    ----> 1 model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, 
    batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, 
   class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, 
   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   778           validation_steps=validation_steps,
   779           validation_freq=validation_freq,
   --> 780           steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
    781 
    782   def evaluate(self,

    \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in 
     model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, 
    val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, 
    validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, 
   steps_name, **kwargs)
   361 
   362         # Get outputs.
   --> 363         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
   364         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
   365           batch_outs = [batch_outs]

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3290 
  3291     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
  -> 3292                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  3293     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
  3294     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, 
 **kwargs)
  1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
 -> 1458         
  1459         if run_metadata:
```

1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

```
 InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape 
 [12,32] and labels shape [72]
 [[{{node 
 loss_23/lstm_72_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
```

Comment: kindly help me i am help less

Comment: I have solved this problem i made input and output shape equal